# updatedTransactions failed to be called back after iOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, storekit

We've been having a tricky problem with store kit. We are trying to implement correctly the in-app purchase renewable subscriptions process into an app that already is on the appStore with standard in-app purchase (non-consumable products) set up.

So far, and after spending 2 months fighting with the sandbox weird behavior, we came up with a working solution on a test iPad running iOS4.2.

Nasty surprise we got when testing this code on a iPad with 4.3 or 5.0, it does not have the same behavior.

We narrowed it down to this simple fact:
- iOS4.2 : the updatedTransactions callback is working properly
- iOS4.3 and above: the updatedTransactions callback is never called by the sandbox.

Any ideas on why a store kit code that works on iOS4.2 wouldn't work on following iOS versions? I didn't see anything deprecated on this.

Here is the code of our updatedTransactions code:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    NSLog(@"Add payment queue");
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)  {
        NSLog(@"Transaction state: %d, %d, %d, %d", transaction.transactionState, SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased, SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed, SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored);
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

                if([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:FM_PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER_SUBSCRIPTION]){
                    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                    [userDefaults setObject:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:@"TransactionReceiptOfTransaction"];
                }

                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction]; 

                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"%@", transaction.error);

                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"") 
                                                                message:NSLocalizedString(@"Your subscription has expired.", @"")
                                                               delegate:self 
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                      otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];
                SAFE_RELEASE(alert);

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];

                if([transaction.error code] != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                    if([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:FM_PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER_SUBSCRIPTION]){
                        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                        [userDefaults setObject:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:@"TransactionReceiptOfTransaction"];
                    }
                }
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:

                if([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:FM_PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER_SUBSCRIPTION]){
                    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                    [userDefaults setObject:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:@"TransactionReceiptOfTransaction"];
                }

                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];

            default:
                    NSLog(@"Other");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Stephane

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem and to solve it I switched the source file which contains the
`addTransactionObserver` call to `ARC = none`.

```
//  StoreKit
CustomStoreObserver *observer = [[CustomStoreObserver alloc] init];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];
```

Seems that ARC or StoreKit framework can't work well together.
To switch a source file with the ARC = none, I set -fno-objc-arc flag as Josh Caswell says it in the "Disable Automatic Reference Counting for Some Files" question.

> The answer is to add -fno-objc-arc to the compiler flags for the files you don't want ARC. In Xcode 4, you can do this under your target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources.

**Update:** My explanation about that behavior is that ARC wants to manage the memory itself but it does not do it well for Storekit. ARC releases too early the 'observer' object. That cause the crash when the InAppPurchase module (Apple side) wants to advise your "updatedTransactions"
method. And for me to stuck 'observer' object in memory during the life of my application. I decided to give it the property retain in my .h file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out! Merci.